# What's the Java configuration version of jpa:repositories tag?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to configure JPA using just Java.

I got the idea that @EnableJpaRepositories would be the equivalent of jpa:repositories tag in xml, but I guess this is not the case?

I have this in my xml:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.myapp.bla.bla" />
```

But if I remove it and instead use

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.myapp.bla.bla")
```

In my java config, I get an exception - I thought it was possible to configure JPA with Java since 1.2.0?

EDIT:

The root exception is:

```
No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
```

I assume the exception has to do with this definition in my config, but as said, everything works if I keep the xml and import it to my java config.

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.myapp.bla.bla.model" });
    factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(props);

    return factoryBean;
}
```

Comment: Please post the exception too in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your current configuration creates a bean called *entityManagerFactoryBean*. However, the error message of your root exception says that a bean named *entityManagerFactory* is not found.

You have two options for fixing this problem (pick the one you like the most):

1. Change the name of the method which configures the *LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean* from *entityManagerFactoryBean()* to *entityManagerFactory()*. This creates a bean named *entityManagerFactory*.
2. Set the name attribute of the *@Bean* annotation to "entityManagerFactory". In other words, annotate the configuration method with *@Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")* annotation. This way you can specify the name of bean yourself and ensure that the name of the annotated method is ignored.

Comment: option 3. set the entityManagerFactoryRef property on the annotation.  This may be new since the question was answered.